# Attach connection with Strophe using Websockets

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

I was using BOSH to attach connection, but I'm deciding to use websockets the only problem is that the method to attach the connection is not implemented in the library.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you figure it out? Thanks